# JScript url replacement

Tags: url, replace, jscript

Ok here it goes, I'm making a JScirpt for a page so you can press a keyboardbutton to move to the next page. The page URL looks like this; http://example.org/12345 , so what i want my script to do is increase the number by 1 each time you press the button. I think most of the code is right but it wont do anything

```
function GoThere() {
var url = window.location.pathname; 
var ew = 'url'+1
url = eq.replace(location.hostname, location.hostname+ew);
window.location = url;
}
```

Would be grateful if someone could take a look and try to explain what I have done wrong

//EniM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check that url is an int, and take the quotes off.  Might use some cleanup, but:

```
// strip out the /
var curint = window.location.pathname.replace(/\D/g,'');

// convert string to int
curint = parseInt( curint, 10 );

var nextint = curint + 1;
window.location = 'http://example.org/' + nextint;
```

Check out the Console in Chrome.  You can run JS line by line... just type a function or var and it will print the result.  Or set break points under Sources.

Comment: If it's 1, it means it's not parsing the path correctly.  If you look at window.location.pathname is there more here than just the int?  You need a string that *looks* just like an integer first, then convert it to an int so you can do the math on it.

Comment: Okay, thank you it kind of works now. Only problem is that the code puts 1 instead of adding ie 123451 instead of 12346, never used ints before but looks like i should, anyways is there anything wrong with my code, it doesnt work but dont know whats wrong

Comment: Sorry, it was just I that messed it up, you code works perfectly, A bug tanks to you =). Now Im just gonna try to understand exactly what the (/\D/g,'') means but google is my friend as allways. Anyways, gonna try to get my code working, does it have to be an int before i do the math or can i do it with it as a string?

Edit- I saw a thing when i copypasted the webpage url, it has /show/ between example/show/12345, does that mean if i have a string Cat123 it will just make the numbers to an int and ignore the letters?

Comment: The replace(/\D/g,'') just means: find everything that's not a number and replace it with nothing. The // is a regular expression, and \D means "not a number".  So it should turn "Cat123" into "123".  Though "123" isn't the same as 123.  One is a string, the other a number.  To be safe only perform math on numbers.  JS will sometimes automatically convert between the strings and numbers, but when it does is not always intuitive.  It's safer to handle the cast manually.

Comment: Thank you for all your help and for explaining everything really good, gonna read more about int =)

Answer (score 1):

i believe your problem relies in this line

```
var ew = 'url'+1
```

it should be

```
var ew = parseInt(url)+1;
```

Comment: Ty, had tomake it to an int first, but have to use window.location.pathname.replace(/\D/g,''); for a clean url, anyways i cant get the rest to work dont really know why, anyways got a working code now =)